# SubSonic - Non-Crud Stored Procedures

Tags: subsonic

I want to create a Data Access Layer for a small application. The stored procedures have previously being created and are not basic CRUD ones. Most are quite custom and don't really map one-to-one to tables in the database. I also need concurrency support.

Can SubSonic / SimpleRepository handle this for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think SimpleRepository will work well in this situation. You might find the LinqTemplates work well to query the data. Subsonic also does a good job handling sprocs and makes it easy to return datasets, or typed results if you have classes that match the structure of your sproc resultsets.

For example, you can map the results of a sproc to a List like this:

```
StoredProcedure sproc = _db.GetProductList();
List<Product> products = sproc.ExecuteTypedList<Product>();
```

All matching columns that can be populated will be.